# Auto scroll all the way to the left on click jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a page that appends inline block divs each time a link is clicked. After a while the total width goes off the page (intentional) I would like the page to do an animated scroll all the way over so the user does not have to drag the scroll bar every time a link is clicked. I have tried but I can not get it to work. Can anyone help me with this?

here is what I tried:

```
var leftPos = jQuery('.container').scrollLeft();
jQuery('.container').animate({scrollLeft: leftPos + jQuery('.container').width()}, 800);
```

but this does nothing once the divs start to go off the page.

Comment: Can you please share a sample generating this set of divs in a fiddle? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
var currentDiv = $("div:last");
$('html, body').animate({scrollLeft: $(currentDiv).offset().left}, 800);
```

Comment: thanks that worked. The animation seems to be really fast I even changed it to 1000 and it just zips across.